# .htaccess doesn't redirect to the https version

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

What I am trying is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both domans `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` works. The first one should redirect to the secured version. What am I doing wrong ? I took a look over the many article around but couldn't resolve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly happens when you type `http://example.com` into your browser?

Comment: just open the site ... with https it is same ...

Comment: Try removing  `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on(s)|` just to see if your rule works without that condition.

Comment: Are there any other working rules in this ,htaccess?

Comment: yes, but they are for loading the configuration file for website only this is for config the http and https